# Check if the strings inside a list of tuples contain whitespace and remove the tuple if true

Tags: python, list, tuples, isspace

I have a list of tuples:

```
[('a', 'a', 'a'), ('b', 'b', 'b), ('c',' \n     \n      \n ', 'c'), ('d', 'd', 'd'),('e', ' \n        \n      \n ', 'e']
```

I want to delete the tuples that contain whitespace. My code is:

```
for tuple in list:
    for string in tuple:
        if string.isspace()  == True:
            list.remove(tuple)
```

It only deletes the second of the tuples with whitespace. If I re-execute the code it deletes the other as well.

Comment: Do not use *list*, *tuple* and any other name of built-in function as name of variable, you're shadowing this function.

Comment: Don't change the contents of a list while you iterate over it, that causes issues

Comment: If you really want to do `operations` while iterating the `list` - you can do this way: for item in lst[::-1]: .....   This will not affect the index for next item.

Comment: As I cant answer, may as well post as comment. `[t for t in inp if not any(n.isspace() for n in t)]`. Where `inp` is your input list.